# Use of polymorphic_url in action mailer to get a full path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have nested resources in my rails application which belong to groups. These items all have comments, and as such the comment file looks as follows:

app/models/comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item, :polymorphic => true
    ...
end
```

I need an ActionMailer which sends the user a link to the item, nested within its specific group. This however has left me banging my head against the wall as how to get the full path into the URL for the link. This is because url_for, when given a polymorphic object calls polymorphic_url on the object, but does not path the options of :only_path => false as the polymorphic_url doesn't take said option. Even in the non-nested resource (second link) it still only gives a path

Currently my mailer view looks as follows:

views/interaction_mailer/new_comment.html.erb

```
Hey <%= @user.name %>!<br />
<br />
<%= @comment.user.name %> just commented on the <%= @item_string %> <%=  link_to @item.title, polymorphic_path([@item.group, @item]) %> in your group (<%= link_to @item.group.name,  @item.group, :only_path => false%>).<br />
```

As I said, this doesn't give me a full path, but instead just a relative one.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to easily get the full path in this email?

PS my config/environments/development.rb file has the following:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'localhost', :port => 3000}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding.  Why is it a problem if `polymorphic_url` doesn't accept `:only_path`?  Don't you want the full url in the email?

Why not simply call `polymorphic_url([@item.group, @item])`?

This should return the full URL, which is what you want, right?

The 2nd link isn't constructed correctly.  You're passing the object as the 2nd arg, and `only_path` as the 3rd, which is being interperted as HTML options.  The ActionView `url_for` helper forces path when using polymorphic routes (the opposite of ActionController's `url_for`... go figure), but you can simply call polymorphic_url to get at the URL in this case.

```
<%= link_to @item.group.name, polymorphic_url(@item.group) %>
```

... should give you the URL.

Comment: The second part now works correctly, however the reason the first part is a problem is because :only_path defaults to true. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/url_for Unfortunately, since polymorphic_url doesn't pass the options to url_for nor does it accept :only_path itself, I can't overwrite it

Comment: `polymorphic_url` doesn't pass options to anything except the resolved named route.  It's essentially the end of the line.  Are you saying that in your example, `polymorphic_url` is returning a path?

Comment: Correct, just a path, nothing else.

Comment: In the sample code you gave it says `polymorphic_path`.  In your real code you are actually calling `polymorphic_url`, right?

Comment: Well sir, two stupid mistakes in one question. Thank you for clearing these up. I tip my hat to you.

Comment: yw.  I've always found a little to be desired with `url_for`, namely that you get a url by default in the controller, and a path in views.  Plus it would be nice to be able to pass options when trying to use named routes.  For those reasons I tend to use named routes directly or polymorphic_(path|url) in all but the most straightforward cases.

Comment: I get this error: `undefined method `polymorphic_url' for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000000000a780>` while accessing it like this `<img src=<%=polymorphic_url(company_logo)%>>` in my view.

Answer (score 0):

Actually as it turned out some of the polymorphic_urls were even necessary as that is only necessary when you need to go to a controller for the polymorphic item, not if the item you are getting happens to come from a polymorphic object. As such the code cleans up to the following:

```
Hey <%= @user.name %>!<br />
<br />
<%= @comment.user.name %> just commented on the <%= @item_string %> <%=  link_to @item.title, polymorphic_url([@item.group, @item]) %> in your group (<%= link_to @item.group.name,  group_url(@item.group) %>).<br />
```